# ScrollView with one child and AutoLayout not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a ViewController setup as follows:

[image]

This is a News app so everything is dynamically loaded, 
once I finish loading data into the Article Title, Article Content, and Image View (the Outer ScrollView) doesn't really scroll

I also checked the ContentView to get its size (just debugging) it gives height: 0px  (Which is the height I initially set for it)

My Background is Android/Java for Mobile development so I set the height to 0, I'm not sure if there's something like "Wrap_Content" in android (-1: internal property value for android as an example).

And in all ways I want to find a way to make ContentView resize dynamically to include all the heights + spacing of its Child Views. and then the Scroll View will show a nice Scroll.

What I tried:

1-Set height of ContentView to e.g (1000) -> it made the ScrollView scroll normally (but such magical numbers are bad).

2-Tried the following code (once I finish loading data into the child views)

```
// Given that the references of the UI elements in my ViewController are:
// scrollView and contentView
- (void)updateScroll{
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // Iterate over SubViews of ContentView
    for (UIView* subView in self.contentView.subviews) {
        subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.contentView.frame.size];
}
```

I debugged using this:

```
NSLog(@"Content view's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
```

And always got this output:

> 2015-05-24 00:30:36.123 NewsApp[18983:2738892] Content view's frame is: {{0,
>   0}, {343, 0}}

Now when I even tried to go through the Child Views one by one using this code:

```
    for (UIView* v in self.contentView.subviews) {
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        totalHeight += v.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"My view %@ frame is: %@",v.class ,NSStringFromCGRect(v.frame));
    }
```

Sizes were as follows: (As you can see ImageView displays height: 0px) --> ruins everything :(

> 2015-05-24 01:59:38.696 NewsApp[20218:3145567] My view UILabel frame is:
>   {{10, 20}, {323, 52.5}}
>
> 2015-05-24 01:59:38.696 NewsApp[20218:3145567] My view UIImageView frame is: {{10, 82.5}, {323, 0}}
>
> 2015-05-24 01:59:38.696 NewsApp[20218:3145567] My view UILabel frame is: {{10,
>   92.5}, {323, 507.5}}

*Constraints*:

1-ScrollView: 0 px from all directions (Horiz. and Vert.)

2-ContentView: 0 px from Horizontal positions and same "width" as ScrollView (tried also to add contraint 0px from top and also tried 0px from top and bottom).

3-Articles Title, Image View, Article Content: 0px horizontal, equal spacing vertical, and placed below each other).

**My Environment:**
Build Target iOS 8, XCode: v. 6.3, Project has AutoLayout enabled of course

**Solution:** Add top and bottom constraint (Vertical to 0) or any fixed number between ContentView and ScrollView, and Add Bottom Contraint between the last element inside the ContentView and the ContentView itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pin your scrollview and contentview to the main view width and height. Then inside the content view, pin the top and bottom of each element to the view and each other, to define the content height based on the height of the elements (with a small space between.)

Check that *all* subviews are pinned vertically in both directions, and there is a continuous series of pins that define the shape of the ContentView. You were missing the bottom constraint from ArticleContentView to the bottom of the ContentView.

Comment: I have already set a Constraint for the spacing on all directions to the parent, isn't that enough to have the width / height dynamically expand to whatever size of the Container ?

Comment: If you set the ContentView to it's parent in height, then wouldn't it always be screen height, and never scroll? It's got to expand beyond screen height, which it can't do if it's pinned that way.

Comment: Scrollviews don't actually expand, they scroll. So the scrollview stays at screen dimensions, but the contentView needs to be expandable.

Comment: I didn't set a height for the contentView as mentioned in my Question, I also tried to set the top/bottom position contraints to 0 but it didn't work

Comment: Take a look at the screen-shot I attached the 2nd block of constraints belongs to the ContentView, it has only Horizonal spacing and Width

Comment: Sorry to only give you suggestions you've already tried! It was hard to read the constraints on the original pic, so thanks for clarifying. When you tested and found ContentView height of 0px, what was the height of the subviews (article, image, etc.)? Could you see them on screen?

Comment: One more suggestion: it looks like maybe you're missing a constraint between the ArticleContentView and the bottom of the ContentView

Comment: Yes, that did it, but also with adding constraint for the ContentView (Vertically) with ScrollView (Top and Bottom to 0), please add this to the Answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: Updated. Yes, that makes sense that the ContentView needs to be pinned vertically to the scrollView, now that I think about it. My layout in my app was different, with multiple "contentViews" in the scrollview, but I still needed to link them together like the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have `wrap-content` int `iOS`
. I suggest defining the height of the `ScrollView`
you dont need to make it has dynamic height since you have a scroll

Comment: no, that'd be really really bad, that's a news app, some articles have only 2-3 lines of content and 1 line title, and no image, and others have literally (50-60 lines of content) (1-3 lines for title) and 1 image (or even more), fixing height for the content is bad, and in my initial tests it broke things, and was looking ugly with huge white scrollable space for short articles

Comment: I'd be fine if there was something like: get the actual size of ContentView since it's definitely not 0px as in the log. (with Actual Size I mean like for Javascript's actual-height vs css's height) , then set the height of the ContentView to the actual measured height.

Comment: You can calculate the actual-height of the article string if you used an attributed string  in a textView .

Comment: how about the spacing constraints and if there are so many views? I'll have to calculate the height of all children, but how to calculate how constraints are rendered (I'm new to iOS so if you believe there's a piece of code that works, post it and I'll test and if it did the job I'll mark it right).